# What is “JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1”? How to debug, without JNI lib's sources? Is CheckJNI helpful for it?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I loading the .so-library using System.load/System.loadLibrary, and application terminating. LogCat contains only this:

> JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1

What can cause this error?
How to debug, if I haven't library's sources?
Can I retrieve a full information, i.e. detailMessage of Java's Exception?
For Java I just used Debugger in such cases, what for C++?

Can CheckJNI help me?

Unfortunately, library is proprietary, close, and we can't contact its author...

Comment: _What can cause this error?"_ Hanging on to a local reference and attempting to use it when it's no longer valid. If the native library does this and you don't have the source then there probably isn't much you can do,

Comment: @Michael but this library properly works inside another Android application.

Comment: Well, we really don't have any way of knowing why that is without seeing the code. Also, the behavior may differ depending on which `targetSdkVersion` the application declares in its manifest.

Comment: The targetSdkVersion shouldn't matter AFAIK. The log message should be followed by the native crash dump, which includes a stack trace pointing to the exact point of failure. Are you calling into the library exclusively from Java-language code, or are you calling it from native code? The latter offers the possibility that you're the one passing the stale reference in, which would be easy to fix. Bugs in closed-source libs provided as binaries can be tricky to work around.

Comment: @fadden "The log message should be followed by the native crash dump, which includes a stack trace pointing to the exact point of failure." But there are no stack trace! Where can I obtain it?